# Is there an elegant way to sum columns in a Vector of Static arrays in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I store velocities for particles as a Vector of SVectors. Each row is an SVector with that indices x, y, z velocity.

SVectors are great for their speed in arithmetic, but they are a bit... difficult to manipulate. How would I add up all of the x, y, z squared velocities in my Vector in a way that is more elegant than the following

```
using StaticArrays
n = 5
v = [SVector{3}(rand(), rand(), rand())  for i = 1:n]
x, y, z = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
for i=1:n
    x += v[i][1]^2
    y += v[i][2]^2
    z += v[i][3]^2
end
sumv = SVector{3}(x, y, z)
```

If I just wanted to sum the x, y, z in my velocities, without squaring, Julia is simple, just `sum(v)` will give me a vector of the summed columns.

One solution I have is

```
sum([v[i].^2 for i=1:n])
```

but there must be a simpler solution that doesn't require a comprehension?

Comment: Comprehensions allocate an array, which you don't need for this reduction. Use a generator instead (just remove the `[ ]`): `sum(v[i].^2 for i in 1:n)`. Better than this is not indexing: `sum(vi.^2 for vi in v)`. The latter is 10x faster than the comprehension. Generally avoid iteration with indices, unless you specifically need the index values.

Comment: Also, rather than initializing with `[SVector{3}(rand(), rand(), rand())  for i = 1:n]`, you can write `rand(SVector{3}, n)`, faster and simpler. Remember to specify eltype if you want something other than `Float64`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sum` function can take a higher order function that transforms each element before it adds them.

```
julia> sum(x->x.^2, v)
3-element SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3} with indices SOneTo(3):
 2.104874346619557
 1.2512923674436118
 1.5781536056190726
```

This gives the same answer as your comprehension:

```
julia> sum(x->x.^2, v) == sum([v[i].^2 for i=1:n])
true
```

Answer (score 2):

What about SMatrices?

```
n=5
mat = SMatrix{3, n}([rand() for i = 1:n*3])

sum(mat .^ 2, dims=2)
```

Comment: This solution is bad for large `n`

Comment: Yes, n doesn't even need to be very large... I think it starts getting slow at n=10, and if I remember, the program starts crashing at n=100.